# Android Compose not refresh with viewModel uiState

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I am doing a simple app in compose in order to learn in, the app has two `viewModels`, `ItemListViewModel` that shows a list of items and `ItemCreateViewModel` that let you create the item, items are stored in Room.

My issue is that when I open the app the list is shown, but after I open the detail and create a new Item, going back the the first (`ItemListViewModel`) the list is not updated.

```
@HiltViewModel
class ItemListViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val itemRepository: ItemRepository) : ViewModel() {

    var uiState by mutableStateOf(value = ItemListState(state = State.LOADING))
        private set

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            itemRepository.fetchItems()
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .collect { items ->
                    uiState = uiState.copy(
                        state = State.IDLE,
                        items = if (items.isNullOrEmpty()) emptyList() else items
                    )
                }
        }
    }
```

and here the Compose view

```
@Composable
fun ItemList(
    viewModel: ItemListViewModel,
    navController: NavController
) {

 
    val items = viewModel.uiState.items
    ShowItems(items)  // <--- this is not called

}
```

this is the repository fun

```
fun fetchItems(): Flow<List<ItemEntity>>
```

If I kill the app and restart it, I can see the new created item.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted here. Can you provide the rest of the code or a link to the project (github for example)?

Comment: here the original code: for this question purpose, I did change **Item** with **Medicine** https://github.com/onivas/MedicineCompose/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/savinoordine/medicinecompose/screen/list/MedicineListViewModel.kt

Comment: I believe you have a threading issue since you're dispatching to the IO thread without going back to the Main thread when updating your `uiState`.

Comment: @ptitvinou I do not think it is a thread issue, the first time I start the app, everything is working fine, items are fetched and dispatched to UI with no issue.

Comment: @PierreVieira see up for project url

Comment: @Onivas I think you forgot to upload the `gradle` folder because I can't compile the project and it's not present on github

Comment: @PierreVieira sorry it was ignored, please pull again now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list doesn't get refreshed because your coroutine gets canceled when navigating to your `CreateMedicineScreen` screen. When you go back to your `MedicineList` screen, the `init` doesn't get called (since it's the same ViewModel instance). You could expose the refresh as a public method from your ViewModel (as you started in your code) and call it from your composable using a side-effect.

```
@Composable
fun MedicineList(
    viewModel: MedicineListViewModel,
    navController: NavController
) {

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.fetchMedicines()
    }

    val medicines = viewModel.uiState.medicines
    ShowMedicines(medicines) {
        navController.navigate(NEW_MEDICINE_ROUTE)
    }
}
```

When you'll pop back to your screen, `MedicineList` will recompose and execute once the fetch method.

As a bonus, I've noticed you had an issue with your navigation back when saving from the `CreateMedicineScreen` screen. It's because you're trying to navigate from a composable. It's also specified in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

> You should only call navigate() as part of a callback and not as part of your composable itself, to avoid calling navigate() on every recomposition.

You could use a side effect here as well:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    navController.popBackStack()
}
```